# __set not being called

Tags: php

I have the __set method below, it's not being fired. Note the `echo '__set'` at the top of the method.

```
public function __set($name, $value){
        echo '__set';
        if($this->{$name}==$value)  return;
        switch($name){
            case 'title':
            case 'body':
            case 'template':
            case 'date':
            case 'pageType':
                if(!$this->exists()){
                    $this->DB->insert('posts', array($name, $value));
                    $this->ID=($this->DB->autoIncrement('posts')-1)<1?1:($this->DB->autoIncrement('posts')-1);
                }
                else{
                    $this->DB->update('posts', array($name => $value));
                }
                $this->{"$name"}=$value;
                return;
            break;
        }
        $this->{$name}=$value;
    }
```

The method works fine when I call `$class->__set(...);` but not when I `$class->title='whatever'`. Hopefully just a small mistype or something but haven't spotted it in the last 15 mins.

Comment: Do you have a property called $title? If so, then I'm pretty sure __set won't get called.

Comment: __set is only called if the property you're trying to assign a value to doesn't exist or isn't accessible. Are you sure your class doesn't have a public $title property already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running into name collisions like those mentioned in the comments to your question, you could instead implement __get() with __set() to accomplish what you're trying to do like so:

```
class MyMagicClass
{
  protected $vals = array();

  public function __get($name)
  {
    if (isset($this->vals[$name])) {
      return $this->vals[$name];
    }
    throw new OutOfBoundsException("$name is not a valid property");
  }

  public function __set($name, $value)
  {
    $this->vals[$name] = $value;
    // do your other stuff here ...
  }
}
```

`__get()`, like `__set()`, is only called when the requested object property doesn't exist or isn't accessible (protected/private). If you do it like the above example, all your "magic" object properties will be stored in the protected `$vals` array and accessed through `__get()` and `__set()`.